# Using strstr() to exclude values in excel while not shifting cells up

Tags: php, strstr

I am working in PHP using strstr() to remove values which are extracted from a MYSQL db to be outputted to an excel file-

**CODE:**

```
        If (!strstr($value, '<script>')){
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);

           $row++;
        }
```

This code excludes the columns that contain a `<script>` tag. However it shifts the contents of the cells up like so:

```
=====================================
|Question          |  Answer        |
=====+========+===============+=====|
|   Male/female    |                |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
|                  |      F         |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
```

Instead I would like it to skip the rows  like so:

```
=====================================
|Question          |  Answer        |
=====+========+===============+=====|
|                  |                |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
|   Male/female    |      F         |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written so that the row is only incremented if your script tag is not found.  However, it sounds like you want to unconditionally increment; if that's the case, then move $row++ to outside the if statement, like so:

```
if (!strstr($value, '<script>')){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
}
$row++;
```

If this isn't what you were looking for, then please provide a sample input that can be matched to the output, as this would make what you need crystal clear.